# Unable to allocate memory for my Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I want to dual boot Ubuntu so in that I have to assign disk space of around 50GB in the unallocated section as shown below.

[image]

I have a PC with 1TB storage out of which the C: drive has 721GB space still left. When I try to shrink the volume to increase my unallocated memory space for Ubuntu it's not giving me that much storage and just gives me 4GB of unallocated memory out of 721GB available.

Comment: This is a problem using windows tools... you really need to ask windows users :)

Comment: To shrink a partition, you need contiguous free space at one end of it. That error message suggests that you don’t have that situation. The Windows tool isn’t letting you move files, seemingly because there are system files in use that occupy space in areas of the partition preventing you shrinking the partition. If there aren’t any Windows tools that let you move those files, I think you’ll be stuck with having to reinstall Windows and then Ubuntu - or get a second drive (eg even a 250GB ssd which is pretty cheap now) if your mobo can take another.

Comment: Always use Windows tools to resize NTFS partitions. If problems, try temporarily disabling system restore, pagefile, (in advanced settings in computer properties) and hibernate option (in power management). Don’t forget to turn them on back later. Use gparted or installer to create Linux format partitions in unallocated space.  Do not shrink NTFS too much as it typically needs 30% free or it starts to slow down.